# Behaviour trees and agent sensors

Tags: java, ai, behavior-tree

Assume I have a behaviour tree like the following:

```
    [A]
   / | \
[B] [C] [D]
```

- A = Selector (Priority node)
- B = Perception task
- C = Idle task
- D = Walk to point task

The reason the tree looks like this is because B has priority over C and D since it should trigger alert procedures. In short, what I'm trying to model here is that the Agent sensors must have priority over behaviours.

Assume now the agent is in D and this node will continue returning `running` until the destination point is reached.

While D is running, something might happen (for instance, the NPC see or hear something) that should break the current operation as soon as possible but, D will go on regardless until it's done.

I know I could paste the sensors code on top of each tree leaf, like for example:

```
// kinda javaish pseudo code
void run() {
    // The node running method
    if (this.sensors.alert()) {
        return this.fail();
    }

    // Else, keep going.
    if (! this.reachedGoal()) {
        // do the walking
        return this.running();
    }

    return this.success();
}
```

But with that solution the "alert" behaviour is hard coded and out of the tree logic.

What solution do you suggest?

Comment: Are you using some library or framework for the implementation of the BT? Are you building your own BTs?

Comment: I was using an external library. I think i ended up coding a custom composite node type with the purpose of intercepting each tick and running the appropriate sensors

Comment: I added a behavior-tree tag :) I agree, I found it strange too.